# canvas.getContext not doing much

Tags: javascript

I've got code that looks like this (I've put the alerts in for testing purposes!):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width=750,height=860,id="maze">HTML5?</canvas>
    <noscript>Javascript?</noscript>
    <script>
        alert("hello! (1)");
        var canvas = document.getElementById("maze");

        alert("hello! (2)");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        alert("hello! (3)");
    </script>
</body>
```

The first and second alerts fire off. The third doesn't. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Use console.log for debugging, and then learn to debug by checking the values of your variables.

Comment: Use the error console to see the `canvas is undefined` exception you're getting!

Comment: How silly of me. Thanks all! Semantics and syntactics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<canvas width=750,height=860,id="maze">HTML5?</canvas>
```

to this:

```
<canvas width="750" height="860" id="maze">HTML5?</canvas>
```

[<kbd>Demonstration</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/6yahfzut/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas from your HTML tag:

```
<canvas width=750 height=860 id="maze">HTML5?</canvas>
```